# Where would I implement an ActionListener?

Tags: java, interface, actionlistener, implements

Where would I implement the following code? By where I mean do I make a new class? Put it in the constructor of my main class? etc.

```
public interface ActionListener extends EventListener {
void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to find a simple tutorial on interfaces and classes

Comment: It can be implement as a new class, a inner class or a anonymous class, depending on your needs

Comment: Take a look at a tutorial like http://portal.aauj.edu/e_books/teach_your_self_java_in_21_days.pdf, I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a class that implements the interface.

```
public class ActionListenerExample implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do something here
    }

}
```

You can then make an object of the class.

```
ActionListenerExample listener = new ActionListenerExample();
```

With Java 8, you could make this more compact by using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```
ActionListener listener = action -> {
    // Do something
};
```

If you don't use Java 8 (which you should) but still want to make it compact, use an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: so what does interface mean?

Comment: @zmi An interface is a type (essentially an abstract class) that provides a blueprint of methods that a class then needs to implement. An interface provides the abstraction of the behaviour while the implementing class provides the implementation of the behaviour.

Comment: @zmi [What are interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example implemented as a local variable:

```
  final ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("Hello World");
      }};
```